# Application returns ENOSYS 38 Function not implemented

Tags: glibc, elf

The func1() which i want to invoke has binding as below:

```
readelf -Ws /lib/libc.so.6 | grep  func1

    592: 000d8910    40 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   12 func1@@GLIBC_2.13
   1690: 000d8910    40 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   12 func2@@GLIBC_2.13**
```

Is this the reason , because of which when I invoke `func1()` from my application it returns an `errno =38` , that is : `ENOSYS 38 /* Function not implemented */`

Can I somehow make the `func1()` binding as GLOBAL and then invoke the same from my application program?

Comment: you asked a compound question about glibc and symbol binding, and then another question receiving a ENOSYS. The answer addresses the ENOSYS but leaves totally unaddressed anything about the large part of your question and the title. I believe this is *too local*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the reason

No. Symbol binding is all about being able to call the function (you can call `GLOBAL`, but not `LOCAL` function) and being able to override the definition (you can link multiple `WEAK`ly defined functions into a single executable without a multiply-defined linker error).

Once you can call the function, its binding is out of the picture, and it returns whatever it returns.

The reason you get `ENOSYS` is most likely that your kernel is too old.

Comment: Is there are way to expose the function func1() from glibc so that it can be used by other applications ?

also func1() is present in system.map file as,
               ffffffff8118e540 T sys_func1                                           

Still why am I getting ENOSYS error ?

Comment: @priyamn "Why ENOSYS?" -- impossible to say. What is `func1`? Does your `System.map` match the kernel you are actually running?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.